# Passing values to the custom components in the Routes

Tags: expression, apache-camel

I am trying to pass values to the custom component in the below route and not using exchange object in the processor etc.,

Input xml message

```
<root>
     <node1>vlaue1</node1>
     <node2>value2</node2>
  </root>



.to("someComponent://foo?param1=staticvalue&param2=${need to send node2 value here})
```

so i tried

```
.to("someComponent://foo?param1=staticvalue&param2=${request.body.root.node2})
```

- which i knw will not work

  .to("someComponent://foo?param1=staticvalue&param2=${request.header.CamelFileName})

  is also not working either

Can anybody point me the mistake iam doing.

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath and store the value in a header:

```
from("file:...")
    .setHeader("myNodeValue", xpath("/root/node2/text()"))
    .to("someComponent://foo?param1=staticvalue&param2=${header.myNodeValue})
```

Not knowing `someComponent`, this approach can be tested as follows:

```
from("file:...")
    .setHeader("myNodeValue", xpath("/root/node2/text()"))
    .log("node2: ${header.myNodeValue}");
```

Or the store the value in a property if the property is needed elsewhere independent from the message:

```
from("file:...")
    .setProperty("myNodeValue", xpath("/root/node2/text()"))
    .to("someComponent://foo?param1=staticvalue&param2=${property.myNodeValue})
```

Comment: This is not working.I actually tried below
 .setProperty("cons",constant("Some Constant"))
 .setProperty("someId",xpath("msg/sourceSystem[1]/text()"))
 .to("someComponent://foo?param1=${header.cons}&param2=${header.someId}")

Comment: Tried with headers,header and properties, proprety

I tried getting the same using 
exchange.getIn().getHeader("cons");
exchange.getIn().getProperty("someId");

Output -> com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@54c01e99


Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: In the example of your first comment you set the properties `cons` and `someId` but you read the `header` instead. In the example of your second comment it is not clear what went wrong as you don't show the whole example, but I guess that your XPath expression is wrong. You could test this expression just as I did in my addional example in my answer by logging the result.